# Spring Controller calls another jsp page and pass the result as ajax response

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, ajaxform

I implement a button that call AJAX to request the data as follows.

```
        $(".load_comment").click(function() {

            $(this).parent().ajaxForm({
                success:function(data) {

                    $('#result').html(data);
                },
                dataType:"text"
            }).submit();
        });
```

Here is my controller to response AJAX request.

```
            @RequestMapping(value = "/get/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public @ResponseBody
            String get(HttpServletRequest request) {

                return "<pre>OK!</pre>";
            }
```

My source code works as expected. I get Text "OK!" showing in div #result.

I would like to know if it is possible to let the controller to call another jsp and return the jsp page result as AJAX response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It is simple.

```
            @RequestMapping(value = "/get/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public @ResponseBody
            ModelAndView get(HttpServletRequest request) {

                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("comment"); // call comment.jsp
            }
```